# Can html element have multiple values in etag attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, etag

Our QA team use etags in our application for searching the right elements on the page.

```
<el etag="accordion.container">...</el>
```

So if the etag value is just a string, than can it have multiple values separated with whitespace ? Like this

```
<el etag="accordion.container user.info">...</el>
```

Or is it a bad practice ? If so, than why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Etag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag), as noted by the tag ([etag](/questions/tagged/etag)) you marked this question with, is an HTTP header.

There is no `etag` attribute in HTML. Using non-standard attributes at all is bad practise.

HTML provides [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) for adding custom data to a document. Their values are custom and freeform so you could define a `data-etag` attribute as holding a space separated list of values. You would just need to ensure that the custom tooling you wrote for processing them expected them to hold that kind of value.